# Which statistical model to apply?

Tags: machine-learning

The dependent variable is continuous. All the predictors are dummy variables. 
Which machine learning methods can we apply to build the models on this kind of data and make prediction?

Thanks.

Comment: this must be a home work or quiz question

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to answer the question. Right now the answer would be "almost anything".

Answer (score 1):

You use good old ANOVA, not Machine Learning.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask for more information about the circumstances the OP has in mind--unless you're willing to maintain that ANOVA might be useful for, say, a million dummy variables or for discrete variables with large numbers of possible values.